# Single Redshift table vs several mysql/ pgsql (on RDS) tables for small (200 tables * 20 columns * 1 million) monthly aggregation data

Tags: mysql, postgresql, performance, amazon-rds, redshift

We're providing SaaS Data Analytics Dashboard for around 200 clients. 
We're using `Amazon Redshift` for storing data in in around 5 tables.
We're getting around  30 million hits per day.

Currently our dashboard is based on raw tables; so its very slow.

We're planning to create aggregation tables on top of `Redshift` tables.
And we're confused between using Single `Amazon Redshift` table vs several small `mysql`/ `postgresql` on (`Amazon RDS`) tables for this small (200 tables * 20 columns * 1 million) monthly aggregation data.

Points we're considering while comparison.

Performance for readonly data.
Cost effectiveness.
Latency difference and its effects on performance.
Maintainability.

Comment: X-post from http://stackoverflow.com/q/31685471/398670

Comment: Do you already have Slaves (alias Replicas)?

Comment: Do you need a few aggregation tables for _each_ of 200 Fact tables?

Comment: Which is it?  MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: @CraigRinger X-post removed.

Comment: @RickJames for redshift we're using 6 nodes

Comment: @RickJames `Postgres` is favorable for us. So consider `Postgres` for comparison.